# How to fix ImagePullBackOff with Kubernetespod?

Tags: kubernetes

I created a pod 5 hours ago.Now I have error:Pull Back Off
These are events from describe pod

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                      From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                     ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    4h51m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nodehelloworld.example.com to minikube
  Normal   Pulling      4h49m (x4 over 4h51m)    kubelet, minikube  pulling image "milenkom/docker-demo"
  Warning  Failed       4h49m (x4 over 4h51m)    kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "milenkom/docker-demo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for milenkom/docker-demo:latest not found
  Warning  Failed       4h49m (x4 over 4h51m)    kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff      4h49m (x6 over 4h51m)    kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "milenkom/docker-demo"
  Warning  Failed       4h21m (x132 over 4h51m)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Warning  FailedMount  5m13s                    kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "default-token-zpl2j" : couldn't propagate object cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Normal   Pulling      3m34s (x4 over 5m9s)     kubelet, minikube  pulling image "milenkom/docker-demo"
  Warning  Failed       3m32s (x4 over 5m2s)     kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "milenkom/docker-demo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for milenkom/docker-demo:latest not found
  Warning  Failed       3m32s (x4 over 5m2s)     kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff      3m5s (x6 over 5m1s)      kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "milenkom/docker-demo"
  Warning  Failed       3m5s (x6 over 5m1s)      kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Images on my desktop

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
milenkom/docker-demo        tagname             08d27ff00255        6 hours ago         659MB
```

Following advices from Max and Shanica I made a mess when tagging

```
docker tag 08d27ff00255 docker-demo:latest
```

Works OK,but when I try
docker push docker-demo:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/docker-demo]

```
e892b52719ff: Preparing 
915b38bfb374: Preparing 
3f1416a1e6b9: Preparing 
e1da644611ce: Preparing 
d79093d63949: Preparing 
87cbe568afdd: Waiting 
787c930753b4: Waiting 
9f17712cba0b: Waiting 
223c0d04a137: Waiting 
fe4c16cbf7a4: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

although I am logged in

Output docker inspect image 08d27ff00255

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:08d27ff0025581727ef548437fce875d670f9e31b373f00c2a2477f8effb9816",
        "RepoTags": [
            "docker-demo:latest",
            "milenkom/docker-demo:tagname"
        ],
```

Why does it fail assigning pod now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
manifest for milenkom/docker-demo:latest not found
```

Looks like there's no latest tag in the image you want to pull: https://hub.docker.com/r/milenkom/docker-demo/tags.

Try some existing image.

UPD (based on question update):

1. docker push milenkom/docker-demo:tagname
2. update k8s pod to point to `milenkom/docker-demo:tagname`

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: `milenkom/docker-demo:latest` docker image does not exist

Comment: I am expecting minikube to take it fron Docker Hub.

Comment: It does not exist on docker hub, check the link :)

Comment: Check if you can run `docker pull milenkom/docker-demo:latest` from a machine which has permissions to your image registry. Also, check which images you have in your image registry - if the image docker-demo exists under milenkom, then make sure that image is tagged with "latest" tag! The issue you're experiencing is caused because the image is not found (possibly does not exist or the tag is incorrect). If the tag "latest" does not exist, simply add one and it shall work, or use the actual tag which the image has.

Comment: docker pull output Error response from daemon: manifest for milenkom/docker-demo:latest not found

Comment: Check your image registry, can you see the image? Look what tag it has, and then use this tag instead of "latest", check if you can pull it.

Comment: Looking into your problem further, I can see you have `tagname` as a tag! you need to make sure it's actually latest, or use this `tagname` instead. To attach a 'latest' for the image, run `docker tag <image name>:latest <registry name>/<image name>:latest`
When you look at the image at the registry, if the image does not exist, make sure to run `docker push milenkom/docker-demo:latest`, make sure it appears in the image registry now, and has the `latest` tag.

Comment: Don't forget you need to push the image with the tag, read more here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/